# Limit of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Does this limit always exist when $f(k)$ is a polynomial?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k!}
$$
(My guess is yes, based on the root test, but I'm not entirely sure I applied it correctly.)

Comment: Start with $f$ being a monomial. Then tackle general polynomials afterwards.

Comment: Yes, because writing $f= \sum  f_k X^k $ you will get  linear combination of series you get from derivating the exponential series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure as

$$F(f) = 
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k!}
$$ is linear and defined for all monomial $f_n(x)=x^n$ as can be verified with the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Therefore it is defined for all polynomials by addition of a finite number of monomials.

Comment: Oh, great, that's a really simple and useful test I wasn't aware of, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^m}{k!}$ converges for each $m \ge 0$. You can use the ratio test to show this series converges. Then note that your original series is a finite sum of series of this form.